# Spring-Hibernate @Transactional service methods do not automatically commit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
@Component
public interface BenefitRateService {
   void save(EmployeeBenefits benefitRates) throws Exception; 
}

@Service(value="BenefitRateService")
public class BenefitRateServiceImpl implements BenefitRateService {

    @Transactional()
    public void save(EmployeeBenefits benefitRates) throws Exception{
        try{
            benefitRateDao.save(benefitRates);
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Component
public interface BenefitRatesDao {
    public void save(EmployeeBenefits benefitRates);
}

@Repository("BenefitRatesDao")
public class BenefitRatesDAOImpl implements BenefitRatesDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory springSessionCtxFactory;

    public void save(EmployeeBenefits benefitRates) throws Exception{

        Session session = springSessionCtxFactory.getCurrentSession();
        //session.beginTransaction();
        springSessionCtxFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(benefitRates);            
        //session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Spring-config.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="springTransactionManager"/> 
<bean id="springTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="springSessionCtxFactory" />
```

```
<bean id="springSessionCtxFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.benefits</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

I am working on a web application that has a user entry EmployeeBenefits form.
I am trying to get the EmployeeBenefits object from the database, modify the object and save again. From the application point of view it seems the data saves and when I retrieve all the data by clicking on List All button, I can see the modified data. But the thing is data never gets updated in the database. 
The saved object gets cached somewhere in the hibernate session but never goes to the database. 
Please help.

By setting log level to Trace, I found the transaction is actually getting committed. Not sure why database table does not update.
Is this because hibernate.connection.autocommit property is not set to true?

```
2017-02-06 21:30:15,765 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager:365] DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [com.vdh.budget.service.impl.BenefitRateServiceImpl.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''    
2017-02-06 21:30:15,786 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager:493] DEBUG - Opened new Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@8f2588] for Hibernate transaction
2017-02-06 21:30:15,788 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager:504] DEBUG - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@8f2588]
2017-02-06 21:30:15,796 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager:183] DEBUG - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@66eb46] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@cdc97b] to thread [main]
2017-02-06 21:30:15,797 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager:258] DEBUG - Initializing transaction synchronization
2017-02-06 21:30:15,797 [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor:362] DEBUG - Getting transaction for [com.vdh.budget.service.impl.BenefitRateServiceImpl.save]
2017-02-06 21:30:15,797 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils:316] DEBUG - Opening Hibernate Session
2017-02-06 21:30:15,806 [org.hibernate.SQL:111] DEBUG - update benefits set amount =? where id =?
2017-02-06 21:30:16,055 [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor:391] DEBUG - Completing transaction for [com.vdh.budget.service.impl.BenefitRateServiceImpl.save]
2017-02-06 21:30:16,055 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager:925] DEBUG - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
2017-02-06 21:30:16,055 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils:144] DEBUG - Flushing Hibernate Session on transaction synchronization
2017-02-06 21:30:16,170 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager:752] DEBUG - Initiating transaction commit
2017-02-06 21:30:16,170 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager:652] DEBUG - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@8f2588]
```

I solved the issue by adding (value = "springTransactionManager") to the @Transactional annotation. 
The problem was I have a HibernateTransactionManager configured which was set up to retrieve the session from the thread

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Spring @Transactional did not work by having that property.
So I configured a new TransactionalMangaer

```
<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
```

```
<bean id="springTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="springSessionCtxFactory" />
```

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/> 
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="springTransactionManager"/> 
<bean id="springSessionCtxFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

In Service class

```
@Transactional(value = "springTransactionManager"})
public void save(EmployeeBenefits benefitRates);
```

By having two transaction managers, @Transactional without qualifier did not pick up the right one that I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: try flush on the session. Alternatively switch to spring-data that has all you need already implemented.

Comment: @ fer.marino Thanks but cannot switch to spring-data right now. However I tried flushing bu it did not work. Any other suggestions?                       Session session = springSessionCtxFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(benefitRates);            
        session.flush();

Comment: first of all i think you don't need put @Component on your interface

Comment: Add the content of `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the wrong `@Transactional` annotation. Spring and JPA have their own versions.

Comment: I am trying to save/update using Spring @Transactional without manual commit. Fetching data from database is working but not save/update operations.